# How to get rid of leading zero in QSpinBox

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am using a QSpinBox that can be used to input values from 0 to 33. The default value is zero. If I use the keyboard to enter numbers it keeps the leading zero, which is annoying.

Example: I want to enter 23 via the keyboard

I type "2" - the value of the spinbox changes to "02"

I type "3" - nothing happens - the spinbox is full

How do I prevent this behavior?

thanks,
A

Comment: Could you show some sample code?

Comment: Are you just placing the cursor after the 0 and typing? Are you selecting all of the text in the spin box first? Deleting it? The default behavior of a QSpinBox is pretty universal, trying to mess with that is generally not good for usability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a line of code in the `valueChanged` listener to remove a leading zero.

```
if (mySpinBox.value.length() > 1 && mySpinBox.value[0] == '0')
{
     mySpinBox.value = mySpinBox.value.remove(0, 1);
}
```

Comment: Which language bindings are you referring to? value is an int, not a QString, so this won't work.

Comment: There is this function : `void QSpinBox::valueChanged ( const QString & text )`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with QDoubleSpinBox where trailing zeros made editing inconvenient.

I solved it by reimplementing the QDoubleSpinBox::textFromValue() to trim the zeros.

Comment: this should be the way to go